# No match for call to struct sockaddr_in

Tags: c++, vector, struct

I am trying to store the address info for each connection to a UDP server.

I have a sockaddr_in struct for the client:

`struct sockaddr_in cli_data;`

My goal is to store this struct each time a new client is connected into a vector of structs and use each element of the vector and therefore each respective struct element later on.

I am declaring the vector like that:

`std::vector<sockaddr_in> cli_addrlist;`

I am then checking whether the recently connected address is present or not, and if it's not - I'm `push_back`-ing the contents of cli_data to the cli_addrlist struct. This is done by the following lines of code:

```
1. bool exists = false;
2. while ((n = recvfrom(s, buf, BUF_SIZE, 0, (struct sockaddr *) &cli_data, &len)) != -1) 
3. {
4.    for (int i = 0; i < cli_addrlist.size(); ++i)
5.    {
6.        if (inet_ntoa(cli_addrlist[i].sin_addr) == inet_ntoa(cli_data.sin_addr))
7.        {
8.            exists = true;
9.        }
10.    }
11.    if (exists == false)
12.    {
13.        cli_addrlist.push_back(cli_data());
14.    }      
15. }
```

The error I'm getting from g++ is:

`error: no match for call to ‘(sockaddr_in) ()’`

which is line 13.

I might have missed something very simple, but I just don't seem to get my head around the issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Ajay, I edited the question now - my mistake, I renamed the variables in order to make it easier to understand but left exactly this one unchanged.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This

```
cli_addrlist.push_back(cli_data());
```

should be

```
cli_addrlist.push_back(cli_data);
```

Also, make sure this struct is suitable for pushing into vector. Like, if it has pointer members as its   data members then it should have copy-constructor/assignment operator corresponding to that.

Comment: Thanks. It worked like a charm. I will also consider the advice, even though my struct has no pointer members :)

Answer (score 1):

Since `cli_data` is a variable, you need to use it this way:

```
cli_addrlist.push_back(cli_data); // No parenthesis
```